# Shopware storefront-watcher for different saleschannels/domains

Tags: shopware, shopware6

is it possible to have the storefront-watcher working for different salechannels with different domains?
Right now it is only working for the domain specified in `APP_URL` for me, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm using `./bin/watch-storefront.sh` to start the watcher.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the flex template (https://github.com/shopware/recipes/blob/main/shopware/platform/6.4/bin/watch-storefront.sh) you could overwrite the APP_URL using

```
APP_URL=http://the-other-storefront.example.com/ ./bin/watch-storefront.sh
```

This should work because the flex template's `watch-storefront` script [restores globally set variables](https://github.com/shopware/recipes/blob/70ce059fc25ccb3511c7cd015f22151b2e820bae/shopware/platform/6.4/bin/watch-storefront.sh#L15), so they can be overwritten.